# large symmetric positive band matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-difference, banded-matrix, intel-mkl

I use **gpbsv** command from **Intel MKL** to solve symmetric positive band system. But unfortunately when the system is large I get an error **Access violating writing location** in VisualStudio.

Could someone give an advice how could I solve this system. Maybe I could use more optimized library? Maybe it's simplier to write my own solver for large problems ( where can I read about realizations ) ?

PS: I have only one notebook with Core i3.

Best wishes.

Comment: How much memory do you have, how big is your system, is it sparse, and if it is sparse, how many nonzeros does it have?

Comment: I'll be honest, there's only one reason I'd expect an error like this: you're passing MKL an invalid pointer. One possibility is that you've tried to dynamically allocate storage for the result, and that allocation failed---but you did not check that fact before proceeding. Or, there could be a similar error elsewhere in your code. Either way, I find it a bit difficult to believe that this error would occur entirely *within* MKL.

Comment: That said, his is likely most memory-efficient way to handle a *dense* banded matrix, at least if you're doing the solve in-place. For sparse matrices I agree with tbirdal.

Comment: @ Geoff Oxberry, almost entire gsm is zero. Each row contains max 27 non-zero elements. 

@Michael C. Grant, the problem was resolved when I linked with libraries with a suffix "_lp64.lib" instead "_ilp64.lib". This problem was also with small systems - Falsely I didn't notice it. -__-

Comment: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mkl_userguide_lnx/GUID-87821148-338B-4022-8C90-F24C866F2878.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a large band matrix, I assume it is sparse and you could well use the sparse solvers in MKL (such as Pardiso or iterative such as conjugate gradients)

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-78889273-7E77-426A-9B5E-23A7C2378D78.htm

Comment: I personally use a code that utilizes pardiso, and its performance is pretty good.  1Mx1M with 50-100 non-zeros per row in tens of ms on only 2-3 cores.

Comment: Yes, it's sparse. Thanks, I'll try Paradiso.